# How to exclusively detect subdomains of a URL with a regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension that is given a list of domains that needs to be compared against the active URL of a tab. For example if the list of domains has
"google" then the extension should detect "docs.google.com" as part of the domain list. I have gotten this part to work. The issue is when the domain list contains a subdomain. For example: if "docs.google" is on the list then if the user is on "google.com" the extension should not recognize this as a URL on the domain list.

I am attempting this by constructing a regular expression. for each domain and subdomain. As I said, when you are given a domain (as opposed to a subdomain) it works properly although I have tested this with subdomains and it does not seem to work. I assume the issue is with how I constructed the RegEx. Anything that stands out? thank you in advance!

```js
let onDomainList = false;
for(let i = 0; i < domainListLength-1; i++){
                if(!domainList[i].includes(".")){ //if this domain is not a subdomain
                    let strPattern = "^https://www\\." + list.domainList[i].replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&') + "|https://[a-z_]+\\." + list.domainList[i].replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
                    let domainRegEx = new RegExp(strPattern,'i');
                    if(domainRegEx.test(activeTab.url)){
                        onDomainList = true;
                        execute_script(activeTab);
                    }
                } else{ //if this domain is a subdomain
                    let strPattern = "^https://www\\." + list.domainList[i].replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
                    let domainRegEx = new RegExp(strPattern,'i');
                    if(domainRegEx.test(activeTab.url)){
                        onDomainList = true;
                        execute_script(activeTab);
                    }
                }
            }
```

EDIT: Changed RegEx to what Wiktor Stribizew suggested, although still the issue of not detecting subdomains.

Comment: You have a `/` at the start, before `^`. You need to remove this `/`. Also, you need to double escape the `.`s since you are using a constructor notation. Also, `domainList[i]` must be escaped. Try `let strPattern = "^https://www\\." + domainList[i].replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&') + "|https://[a-z_]+\\." + domainList[i].replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');`. And then also `let strPattern = "^https://www\\." + domainList[i].replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');`

Comment: Seems that the same problem exists of not detecting subdomains. Although what you said does work for normal domains.

Comment: Maybe because you do not match anything but `www` and `list.domainList[i]`? Try matching anything but `/`: `let strPattern = "^https://(?:[^\\s/]*\\.)?" + list.domainList[i].replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');`. It is hard to help without one or two test cases.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I understand your explanation or provided Regex. Regardless this did work! I thought I understood RegEx decently but the line you provided doesnt look like anything to me. Either way I really appreciate you answering this, thank you.

Comment: I will add the answer with explanations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fixed snippet:

```js
let onDomainList = false;
for (let i = 0; i < domainListLength - 1; i++) {
  if (!domainList[i].includes(".")) { //if this domain is not a subdomain
    let strPattern =
      let strPattern = "^https://www\\." + domainList[i].replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&') + "|https://[a-z_]+\\." + domainList[i].replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
    let domainRegEx = new RegExp(strPattern, 'i');
    if (domainRegEx.test(activeTab.url)) {
      onDomainList = true;
      execute_script(activeTab);
    }
  } else { //if this domain is a subdomain
    let strPattern = "^https://(?:[^\\s/]*\\.)?" + list.domainList[i].replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
    let domainRegEx = new RegExp(strPattern, 'i');
    if (domainRegEx.test(activeTab.url)) {
      onDomainList = true;
      execute_script(activeTab);
    }
  }
}
```

**Notes**:

- Since you are using a `RegExp` constructor notation, and define the regex with a regular string literal, you need to properly introduce backslashes used to escape special chars. Here, there is no need to escape `/` and the `.` needs two backslashes, the `"\\."` string literal is actually a `\.` text
- The variable texts need [escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3561493/3832970) to be used properly in the code, hence `domainList[i].replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')`
- The `/` before `^` renders the regex useless since there can be no `/` before the start of string, and thus `/^` is a regex that never matches any string. `/` as regex delimiters should not be used in `RegExp` constructor notation
- A subdomain regex does not actually match anything but `https://www.` + the domain from your list. To allow anything before the domain, you can replace `www\.` with `(?:[^\s/]*\.)?` that matches an optional sequence (`(?:...)?` is an optional non-capturing group) of zero or more chars other than whitespace and `/` (with the `[^\/s]*` negated character class) and then a dot.

Comment: the .replace(....) used as a .escape method, this is used for when there is a special character in the string the regex ignores it? Everything else you said makes sense and I appreciate the work you put in.

Comment: @Jonnes Right, if there are no special chars, no replacement will be done. If the list items only contain letters, digits or underscores, remove this.

Comment: got it. I can see how that is crucial to have. Thank you again.